# How can I start an interactive python/ipython session from the middle of my python program?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a python program which first does some tasks, and then in certain conditions goes into an interactive mode, where the user has access to an interactive python console with the current program's scope. Right now I do this using the code module by calling code.InteractiveConsole(globals()).interact('') (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html).

My problem is that the resulting interactive console lacks some functionalities that I usually get with the standard python console (i.e. the one you get by typing 'python' in a terminal), such as remembering the previous command, etc. Is there a way to get that same interactive console in the middle of my python program, or even better yet ipython's interactive console?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: I have no idea whether the following will work, and if it works, I have no understanding why, but try importing `readline` before you run `code.InteractiveConsole(globals()).interact('') `. That seemed to solve a similar problem I had once.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use [`IPython.embed()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable//interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython) where you're currently using `code.InteractiveConsole(globals()).interact('')`.

Make sure you're importing IPython before you do that, though:

```
import IPython
# lots of code
# even more code
IPython.embed()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin **[`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint)** function (Available in Python 3.7+) to launch the interactive IPython shell with **[`IPython.embed()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.terminal.embed.html#IPython.terminal.embed.embed)**. This is nice as it is shorter to type (and does not need an import).

By default `breakpoint()` launches a python debugger. To make it launch the ipython shell, you have to set the environmental variable `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` to be `IPython.embed`.

**On Linux**:

Run or add to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
export PYTHONBREAKPOINT="IPython.embed"
```

---

For more info about `breakpoint()`, see [PEP 553](https://peps.python.org/pep-0553/)